# Snapping (resizable) items to grid with interact.js

Tags: interactjs

I'm trying to get my resizable items to snap to a grid (using InteractJS). I have defined the draggable config as follows:

```
draggable = {
    modifiers: interact.modifiers.snap({
        targets: [interact.snappers.grid({ x: 5, y: 5 })],
        range: Infinity,
        relativePoints: [
          { x: 0, y: 0 },
        ],
    })
}
```

The items snap to the grid just fine, but I'm seeing some weird behavior. My items top left corner is placed at `0,0`. Then if I drag the item along the y-axis, the initial jump goes to `0,1`, then it follows the grid correctly afterwards `0,6`, `0,11` etc.

Same with the x-axis, if the item is at `0,0` and gets dragged to the right the initial jump is 3px, so to `3,0` and then afterwards the grid is followed; `8,0`, `13,0` etc

How do I set the corner point of the grid to be at `0,0`? It seems the grid is slightly misaligned from the div the items reside in. Note that I do want to be able to drag items outside their container div, but I want `0,0` to be a snappable position and not `3,1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working with the following config:

```
draggableModifiers.push(
      interact.modifiers.snap({
        targets: [interact.snappers.grid({ x: 5, y: 5 })],
        range: Infinity,
        relativePoints: [
          { x: 0, y: 0 }, // snap relative to the element's top-left
        ],
        offset: "self", // adding this fixed the misalignment issue
      })
    );
```